# I don't know the name of the following 4-pin connector

Tags: connector, identification, surface-mount

I want to replace an SMD connector on the following PCB, but I do not know how to search for it, in order to buy it.

I have attached a photo from the male connector, it might help. Can you name it?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is it connecting to? Looks like some non-standard USB connection (I have something similar on my DSLR)

Comment: It is connecting to a finger probe for measuring sp02 and heart rate from NoNin. The product is OxyPro from Card Guard but i can not find any info.

Comment: My first thought was a mini-firewire, but looking at those again it's not quite the right shape.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looks like usb mini 4 pin connector. I have same connector on my helicopter RC-model.

Comment: Do you have the name of the connector? This certainly isn't a standard mini-USB connector.

Comment: milssky - "*usb mini 4 pin connector*" Unfortunately, no. :-( Notice the "bump" in the entry hole of the PCB-mounted connector and the corresponding "notch" on the cable mounted connector. That means it is not as simple as just being a normal USB Mini-B.

Comment: I dont know the name but i guess the following is going to fit https://www.ebay.com/itm/USB-Mini-B-Female-Socket-Rubber-Cover-SMT-SMD-Solder-Mounting-Assembly-Connector/182913663522?epid=1988799763&hash=item2a96810222:g:bBkAAOSwSPBae4ms:rk:12:pf:0

Answer (score 2):

I think it is a Sony Mini B 4-pin connector.

Comment: Looking it up, that looks similar. Could you add supporting images and information to improve the answer?

Comment: Strange world where an obviously wrong answer has multiple upvotes and even an erroneous accept, while no less than three people downvoted this likely correct one.  There is absolutely no requirement that an answer include a picture.